# Does RPi 3 have the same bandwidth for ethernet and USB?

Tags: usb, wifi, pi-3

It seems that's the case for the last Pi. But does the new one also have this limitation?

`Not duplicate, but reffered question:   
  USB bandwidth for the RPi model B+`

Comment: Yes, but the Pi 3 has built in WiFi which means you don't need Ethernet and so all of the bandwidth can be used for USB.

Comment: So the WIFI has its own bandwidth?

Comment: That is correct